# How to create a new target that will use the same codebase but a different product name?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

We use `CocoaPods`, so a workspace is used. We have also created two different targets: one target is for production `MyApp`, and the second target is for development `DevelopMyApp`. That was done because we need to create a separate product name `DevelopMyApp` when developing and uploading to TestFlight. Currently targets are duplicated, so I want to remove classes from compile sources in `DevelopMyApp` target and add target dependency. However, that builds and compiles `MyApp` and makes `MyApp.app.DSYM` file instead of desired `DevelopMyApp` and `DevelopMyApp.app.DSYM`. Is it possible to have two targets with dependency but have separate product and `DSYM` name when building child target?

**UPDATE** The problem with current solution of "duplicated targets" is we need to add new classes to both of targets every time. And if we forget to add a new class to `DevelopMyApp` then we will need manually to go through each of them and find missing ones (or check that by errors). I just need to add reference from `DevelopMyApp` to primary `MyApp` target so all classes should be included from it.

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to have one target "subclass" another. The only way to have two apps that share large portions of code, but still have differences in the code or resources, is to have two separate targets have new files added to each and old files removed from each. If the two apps are exactly the same, except for the name, then you may be able to edit the plist, but submitting duplicate apps to the app store is going to be a red flag in the review process.

Comment: There is no solution for that. All you can do is to check if both have the same amount of files in Build Phases - to make sure you have same classes on both.